# I need to export DXFs with a certain Z value

Tags: qgis, elevation, dxf, xyz

How do I do that? Right now it says it's including a Z dimension but I don't know where to input it.[image: what I get when I click "export" then "save as"]

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes that you want to have a uniform Z value for the entire geometry.*

Before you export the data do the following.

Open the Processing Toolbox and under Vector Geometry choose Set Z Value. Choose the Z value that you want the source data to have and save it as a **new** dataset (don't delete or save over the original just in case). This will embed a Z value in the geometry of the dataset.

Now export this new dataset to dxf and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Select by expression from the attribute table to select specific values based on Z elevation of the geometry using the following formula:

To select a specific value:

```
z_min($geometry) = 500

#change the 500 for the value you need
```

Output:

[image]

To select more than one value:

```
z_min($geometry) = 500 or z_min($geometry) = 1000     

#change the 500 and 1000 for the values you need
```

Output:

[image]

To select range of values:

```
z_min($geometry) >= 500 and z_min($geometry) <= 1000

#change the 500 and 1000 for the values you need
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that I don't have a Z column in the attribute table. Finally, right-click the layer in the table of content, go to `Export`, then `Save Selected Features As` to save those features.